dart run build_runner build depends on flutter_test from sdk which doesn't exist (the Flutter SDK is not available), version solving failed
After updating to the newest version of Flutter recently I have been facing this problem continuously and don't know what to do.
As one solution I am using:
flutter pub run build_runner build

Instead of:
dart run build_runner build

Flutter version:

Flutter 3.22.0 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 5dcb86f68f (13 days ago) • 2024-05-09 07:39:20 -0500
Engine • revision f6344b75dc
Tools • Dart 3.4.0 • DevTools 2.34.3

This is the error I got after a recent Flutter upgrade:


❯ dart run build_runner build
Resolving dependencies in /home/marlin/code/flutterApp/graphland-dev/dinebd_partner_mobile_app...
Because dinebd_partner_mobile_app depends on flutter_test from sdk which
doesn't exist (the Flutter SDK is not available), version solving failed.

Flutter users should use flutter pub instead of dart pub.
Here is the pubspec.yaml file:
name: dinebd_partner_mobile_app
description: "A new Flutter project."
# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `flutter pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: "none" # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=3.4.0 <4.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  flutter_riverpod: ^2.4.10
  go_router: ^14.1.1
  flutter_secure_storage: ^9.0.0
  dio: ^5.4.0
  shared_preferences: ^2.2.2
  geolocator: ^10.1.0
  # network_info_plus: ^4.1.0
  flutter_screenutil: ^5.9.0
  flutter_svg: ^2.0.9
  shimmer: ^3.0.0
  flutter_hooks: ^0.20.4
  graphql_flutter: ^5.1.2
  cached_network_image: ^3.3.1
  fluttertoast: ^8.2.4
  url_launcher: ^6.2.3
  form_validator: ^2.1.1
  flutter_otp_text_field: ^1.1.1
  dropdown_button2: ^2.3.9
  dotted_border: ^2.1.0
  equatable: ^2.0.5
  intl: ^0.19.0
  carousel_slider: ^4.2.1
  image_picker: ^1.0.7
  google_maps_flutter: ^2.5.3
  flutter_rating_bar: ^4.0.1
  json_annotation: ^4.9.0
  freezed_annotation: ^2.4.1
  #  flutter_json_view: ^1.1.3
  hooks_riverpod: ^2.4.10
  dotted_line: ^3.2.2
  uuid: ^4.3.3
  crypto: ^3.0.3
  flutter_html: ^3.0.0-beta.2
  flutter_widget_from_html: ^0.14.11
  logger: ^2.2.0
  lottie: ^3.1.0
  chat_bubbles: ^1.6.0
  flutter_reaction_button: ^3.0.0+3
  analyzer: ^6.4.1

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_lints: ^3.0.1
  build_runner: ^2.4.8
  freezed: ^2.4.7
  json_serializable: ^6.7.1
  graphql_codegen: ^0.13.11

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true

I want to run:
dart run build_runner build

and still work like before, anybody knows what to do.

I was able to resolve this by using FVM (Flutter Version Manager).
After installing FVM, run
fvm use x.x.x # eg, 3.19.0

Then
fvm dart run build_runner build

And hopefully your issue will be resolved.
In general FVM has resulted in way less headaches working with Flutter.
